# How to Content lock a video after 10 seconds of play it?

Tags: php, javascript, html, video, onload-event

thanks for your time! how would i go about having my content locker, load and pausing the video after 10 secs

So the user hits play, the video (self hosted) plays and after 10 seconds of playing it pause/stops and loads my content locker

`onClick='show_locker();'`

`onload='show_locker()'`

I was guessing i'd have to use html5 video player and JavaScript?  i'm not brilliant with JavaScript hence my question?

`<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>`

Any help or code would be great!

Comment: Where have you looked so far, have you looked at any of the many html5 video players out there all with good documentation?

Comment: I can still download your video if your intention is to block me ...

Answer (score 0):

use `settimeout` function

```
function showlocker(){

/////
your code
/////

setTimeout(function(){pauseaudio(),10000)}

}

function pauseaudio(){

song.pause();

}
```